# Mathematical rigour in Signal and Systems

Tags: signal, fourier

I'm an electronics engineering student with high inclination to analysis and pure mathematics ( abstract algebra/linear algebra ... ).   I was just wondering if there was any book ( or any resource ) that treats signal and systems and signal processing with a lot of mathematics rigour ( actually doing proper complex analysis, using functional analysis and linear algebra rigorously to explain convolution, fourier, laplace and z transforms for example ).

I'm very disapointed with the books i've read ( Oppenhein, Lathi and related ) because it actually throws a lot of the beauty of analysis and algebra away, focusing on the computational side.

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is engineering, where we throw out the analisys and keep the answer.  You want math, where they throw out the answer and keep the analisys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This xkcd comic comes to mind.

[image: Fields by purity]

EE is some kind of hybrid of applied physics and mathematics. It's easy for a mathematician to pick up an electronics book and move to the left. It is not as easy for a EE to pick up an advanced mathematics book and move to the right.

For most practical things, the the math is well understood. For example, filters are commonly developed from canned topologies, and most practicing EEs let MATLAB or other software do the number crunching. It's just not worth the time it would take to work through all of the transforms manually to get the transfer function, especially for filters higher than second order. If the filter is going to be implemented digitally, all it takes is a z transform and some algebra to get to a difference equation.

The majority of the guys that care about the math at the level you're interested in are researchers. You might look at the Proakis signal processing and communications books. They have quite a bit of math in them, but your expectations aren't clear enough to me to say whether you'll be satisfied with them. You would probably be better served to look for straight math books that cover the topics of interest. Unfortunately, I cannot provide any recommendations there. That question may be better suited for Math.SE

Answer (score 2):

Besides lecture notes or basic books about signal processing and communications engineering, I like "Wideband Amplifiers" by Peter Staric and Erik Margan (2006); it offers a lot of good math and extends this to transistor-level amplifier design ([Sample)](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/0-387-28340-4WBA_demo.pdf). However, it doesn't offer a lot of background on sampling and digital signal processing - but any *good* communications engineering 101 will, like, maybe, [here (MIT, English)](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-36-communication-systems-engineering-spring-2009/lecture-notes/) or [here (TUM, German)](http://www.lntwww.de/downloads/Signaldarstellung/Theorie/).

A very good one on network analysis is "Linear and Nonlinear Circuits" by Chua, Leon O., Desoer, Charles A. and Kuh, Ernest S. 1987. McGraw-Hill. ISBN 0070108986.

Using books like these for theory and reading [The Art of Electronics](http://frank.harvard.edu/aoe/) when it comes to practical circuit design will be very useful and get you pretty far.

Answer (score 2):

"Mathematical Methods and Algorithms for Signal Processing", by Todd K. Moon goes through the linear algebra, at the EE grad level, used in signal processing.

This is a link to Amazon:

[http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Methods-Algorithms-Signal-Processing/dp/0201361868](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201361868)

See also "A Wavelet Tour of Signal Processing", by Mallat. The first chapters are about Fourier Transforms, sampling, uncertainty principle, etc.

[http://www.amazon.com/Wavelet-Tour-Signal-Processing-Third/dp/0123743702/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1368539706&sr=1-1&keywords=mallat+wavelet](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123743702)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you realize how ironic your question is.  You talk of "pure" mathematics and yet every field of mathematics that you mention (with maybe one exception) in your purity list is considered to be in the "applied" math field and would hardly meet the criteria that mathematicians would consider as pure.  This is especially ironic given your interest in signal processing since that does in some cases delve quite deeply into topology and multi dimensional math and what not.

The good news is that  yes there are a lot of these sorts rigourous analysis' but it's mostly in the original papers in the seminal articles. Here is a short list:

1) Andrew Viterbi with trellis decoding,

2) Cooley and Tukey with the original cooley tukey algorithm, became known as the FFT, actually originally by Euler.

3) Shannon and signals theory.

I suspect most books that you're dissing as not being rigorous enough have references and citations, follow up on the articles cited. Most authors don't spend a lot of time in depth analysis in text books for the obvious reasons that they don't need to prove that, for presumably the upteenth time, that this meets all the necessary rigour.  Look more towards graduate level texts as well.

Particular journals in no particular order or reason:

a) Chaos and bifurcation theory, but even that has applied in it's full title.

b) Arxiv.org

c) plos.org

Comment: "Cooley and Tukey with the original cooley tukey algorithm, became known as the FFT, actually originally by Euler." I think FFT was originally by Gauss. See for instance www.cis.rit.edu/class/simg320/Gauss_History_FFT.pdf‎

Comment: Gauss was only 6 years old when Euler died.  They have found butterfly calculations in the marginalia of Eulers notebooks.

Comment: Interesting! Do you know were I can find more info about that?